# select from 2 tables and order them in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to select some rows from different tables and then i want to order them. how can i merge these results and order them according to their created_at values?

```
@books = Book.all
@notebooks = Notebook.all

@booksandnotebooks = ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@booksandnotebooks = (@books + @notebooks).sort_by(&:created_at)

Isn't ruby lovely :)

Comment: This also seems to be a good candidate for normalizing books and notebooks?

Comment: yeah.  Nanni - if you do want to go down the route of sharing code/functionality between books and notebooks (which i think is what shane is suggesting), i'd recommend steering clear of single table inheritance (STI) which is nothing but pain in my experience, and instead look at writing a module in the lib folder which both books and notebooks can include.